# Web API 4 Ninject and "Sequence contains no elements"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My issue is that After i publish the WebAPI to the production environment everything is working fine. The logs are showing requests and responses being processed and this state remains for a long time ( 4hrs +).

However over night the site goes down and in the morning the site is displaying the error below. I cannot restart the site through IIS and get a clean state. In order to start the site up again i need to republish the site and everything starts working again.

Can anyone help?

Here is the error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +379
Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.Start() +73
Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) +136
Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback) +204

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +229
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +193
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +341
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +854
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods(Boolean designerMode) +47
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +189

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +12967707
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +12967416
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean&amp; isRefAssemblyLoaded) +280
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12966756
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12806561
```

Here is the production environment:

- I am using a windows server 2012 platform
- Ninject (3.0.0.0)
- Ninject.Web.Common (3.0.0.0)
- Ninject.Web.MVC (3.0.0.0)
- WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject (0.9.3.0)

Here is the Global.ascx.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //TracingConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
}
```

Here is the NinjectWeb.Common.cs:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ScenicTours.Services.UI.WebService.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(ScenicTours.Services.UI.WebService.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            // Support WebAPI 
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // Normal Bindings here....
    }        
}
```

IIS Configuration:

- App Pool is set to "Idle Time-out(minutes)" 20

Comment: Is this shared hosting? I'd say your app pool is being recycled, or some sort of maintenance is breaking your bindings.

Comment: I would put a log in on stop, see if its being called at all.

Comment: Luke: Are you suggesting that the Global.ascx application_stop event to put a log event here?

Comment: Luke: I used the Global.asax Application_End event and found the application does go through this method when it closed down.